# How to use a forEach loop on dynamically created elements

Tags: javascript

I am looking to add draggable functionality to my todo list project,

I am trying to use a forEach loop to loop over my elements and for now just change the opacity of each div when dragged. However I can not find a way for this to work on elements which I have created, the draggable attribute is added but they dont work with the loop.

```
function addTodo() {
const todoDiv = document.createElement('div')
todoDiv.classList.add('todo')

const newButton = document.createElement('button');
newButton.classList.add('todo-button')

const newLine = document.createElement('div')
newLine.classList.add('line')

const newTodo = document.createElement('li');
newTodo.innerText = todoInput.value
newTodo.classList.add('todo-text')

const newDelete = document.createElement('button');
newDelete.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-times "></i>'

newDelete.classList.add('delete-todo')
todoList.appendChild(todoDiv)
todoDiv.appendChild(newButton)
todoDiv.appendChild(newLine)
newLine.appendChild(newTodo)
newLine.appendChild(newDelete)


var att = document.createAttribute("draggable");
att.value = "true";
todoDiv.setAttributeNode(att); 
}

todo.forEach(todo => {
todo.addEventListener('dragstart', () => {
    todo.classList.add('dragging')
  })
})
```

TLDR

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqxub17t/3/), when you create a new todo item it doesnt seem to be picked up by the forEach loop and apply the class

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Works fine, the element is styled (not the drag ghost). [Forked  example](https://jsfiddle.net/un9y6ftL/). It's not clear why you're not seeing what I see.

Comment: Works for me also, maybe try another browser?

Comment: @RamblinRose sorry the way I worded the question wasn't the best, I mean, if you type something into the box that says "Create a  new Todo..." and press enter a new item is added, however I can not get that element to be styled like the others using a forEach loop and I am not sure why. Thank you anyway for taking the time in  looking and trying to help!

Comment: @ElliotCase OK I understand.  Your `addTodo` method is *not* adding an event listener.  e.g. `todoDiv.addEventListener('dragstart', () => {   
      todoDiv.classList.add('dragging')
    })`